# Cant access nodejs server using machine ip address instead of localhost

Tags: node.js, windows, tcp, port, firewall

**I am using windows 10 as OS**

Iam trying to access my node.js server from another device browser in the same network using my device ip address in our network--> ipv4 `192.168.X.X` " its obtaind using `ipconfig`in cmd"  and port "4000", i did the following configration in my code:

```
module.exports = {
  server: app,
  start: (port) => {
    const PORT = port || process.env.PORT || 4000;
    server.listen(PORT,'0.0.0.0', () => { console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`); });
  },
};
```

I also opened the inbound ports from windows firewall rules for ports 80, 443, 4000.
[FireWall Rules Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hpwf.png)

> When I tried: http://localhost:4000/     -->it works.

> When I tried: http://192.168.X.X:4000/   -->it didn't work.

- The weird thing is that when I run the same setup on Linux "ubuntu" it works with the same code above "after opening the ports using: `ufw allow 80,443,4000 proto tcp`".

## For debugging with cmd I tried:

1. `netstat -a -o` and I got that node is working in localhost:4000 rather than 0.0.0.0:4000

EX: `TCP  127.0.0.1:4000  DESKTOP-T18TEC0:0  LISTENING  11628`

How I can make it 0.0.0.0:4000 so I can access node.js server by device-network IP 192:168.X.X?

2. Ping my ip "192.168.X.X" and its pingable.

Comment: by the way: no need to hide 192.168 addresses ... mines `192.168.1.69` - won't do you any good knowing that :p

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us *precisely* went wrong. Did you connect with a browser on your own machine? What error message did you see? (Your code looks OK. Listening on `0.0.0.0` means listening on all network interfaces. You probably have two of those, one for localhost and 127.0.0.1 and another for your machine's 192.168.x.y address.)

Comment: *I also opened the inbound ports from windows firewall rules* I never had to manually do that - first time I tried running a node server, windows asked me if I wanted to allow it, and `node.exe` was given permission to listen on the LAN

Comment: @O.Jones node server is not accessible from the browser either from the same machine or another machine in the same network, error msg: "This site can't be reached", I'm hitting: http://192.168.X.X:4000 in the browser.

Comment: that's because your code isn't listening on 192.168 only on localhost - perhaps it's a firewall misconfiguration - one tab from the firewall config page isn't enough to know what you may have done wrong there

Comment: @Bravo I am using  192.168.X.X to show that I tested this issue in more than one network with a different gateway, of course, it's not for security reasons (:

Comment: @Bravo as O. Jones mentioned above 0.0.0.0 should allow access from any IP address in port 4000 so no need to statically type my IP address  "192.168...." in the listening expression.

Comment: ok, no probs - anyway, your firewall rule may be the problem - do you allow all interfaces? Is there anything in Remote Users tab? Is this rule for all programs or specifically node.js - oh, and I do understand what "0.0.0.0" means - thanks anyway - I just find it odd that you manually added a firewall rule to begin with

Comment: have you checked if anything else may be listening to 192.168.x.x:4000? Have you tried a different port? have you tried deleting the firewall rule and any other firewall rules that pertain to node.exe? Have you tried turning firewall completely off, just to test of course

Comment: Yes, @Bravo, I did all the steps you mentioned and that's what makes this issue somehow weird.

Comment: right, so even with the firewall OFF, the request fails? and the server code only listens on localhost? never network interface?

Comment: yes, @Bravo, When I use `netstat -a -o`  I got that node.js server is binding on 127.0.0.1:4000 rather than 0.0.0.0:4000
EX: `TCP  127.0.0.1:4000  DESKTOP-T18TEC0:0   LISTENING  11628`

Comment: so, if you change to port 3999 for example, it binds to 127.0.0.1:3999 not 0.0.0.0:3999?

Comment: @Bravo, exactly.